# Port Forwarding on a router which is behind another NAT (multiple port forwarding)

Tags: python, sockets, p2p, portforwarding, nat

I have a **p2p** app and I want to know If is it possible to forward a port on a router behind another router. Currently I can forward a port on the direct router with a **python** script but when the 2 users are behind a Nat behind another **Nat**, I don't know how I can do that. Here is the schema of the situation

```
                               user1
                                 ||
                                 ||
                            first router
                                 ||
                                 ||
                            second router
                                 ||
                                 ||
                                 ||
                              Internet
                                 ||
                                 ||
                            second router
                                 ||
                                 ||
                            first router
                                 ||
                                 ||
                                 ||
                                user2
```

**Note**: users can have 2 or more routers, 2 is just a case, but I think that If I can do with 2, I can do with more.

Every help is greatly appreciated

### To Forward a port on a single router

- I can use miniupnpc it works on python 2.x (On Linux)

below is the code

```
 import miniupnpc

 def forward_port(port, description=''):
    upnp = miniupnpc.UPnP()
    upnp.discoverdelay = 10
    upnp.discover()
    upnp.selectigd()
    port = port
    # addportmapping(external-port, protocol, internal-host, internal-port, description, remote-host)
    upnp.addportmapping(port, 'UDP', upnp.lanaddr, port, description, '')
```

- Otherwise I use this [very long script](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3XGn7xdfoSNWHNHa0lNNTMtUWc) which works on python 2.x but on every os

Comment: please show some of your code since you are posting on this Stack Forum

Comment: @OTTO the code that I have can just forward a port on a single router and I don't even know how to do that with more than one

Comment: A properly implemented router can forward mapping requests to the next router. If all in the chain support that everything should work out of the box.

Comment: @the8472 so you are saying that I don't have to worry about other routers ?

Comment: That's not what I said at all. The *properly implemented* part is critical. Cheap plastic toys that pass as consumer grade routers often do not support what is necessary or if it is supplied by the ISP they may have disabled that feature for whatever reason with modified firmware. And the manual or spec sheet won't tell you either. And CGNAT is another thing to worry about. And then there are several different protocols to negotiate port forwarding...

Comment: @the8472 ok thank you for your clarification